# Android Studio Toolbar Automatically showing up

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a brand new Android developer coming over from iOS development.  All I want to do right now is launch an app with a basic Toolbar using api 21.  However, when I do do, it adds the toolbar underneath a seemingly identical bar.  Upon removing the toolbar, the other bar is still present.  Is this default for all Android apps to have a toolbar with the app name built into the top? How do I add actions/customize this default toolbar?

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout"></LinearLayout>
```

And here is my main activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //toolbar.setTitle("Groups");
}
```

}

[image: This is the result of the code I listed]

This is literally the extent of my project, and though I have been searching online for a while everyone says I should be using a Toolbar.  If this is not a Toolbar then what is it then?  I apologize for my naivety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set this in your styles to hide default ActionBar.

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

In your layout, you can add ToolBar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

And in activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did set <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> in my styles.  Does <item name="windowNoTitle"> differ from <item name="android...">?

Comment: Should my AppCombat theme by .NoActionBar or .DarkActionBar?

Comment: If you don't want a default ActionBar, you should customize your styles .NoActionBar, and set this for your activity.

Comment: Can I add actions to the default action bar, or do I have to make my own for this?

Comment: Of course you can. Just add menu xml, and override `onCreateOptionsMenu ` and `onOptionsItemSelected `